# How to create a method that you can call in all other controllers in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, controller

Greetings guys i'm having a challenge figuring out how to make this method in the base controller so that i initialize it there and call it in all other controllers that i wish.
I want to create this in the base controller , then call it in other controllers

```
    $paynow = new Paynow(
        '9644',
        '7e3bebb4-6dbf-4f8f-9e10-aceafd02c8db',
        'Return_url',
        'Result_url'
    );
```

Images
1.This is what i have done in the base controller

[image]

Image 2. This is where im trying to use it to call its member functions

[image]

Image 3. Is the error that  im getting
[image]

Comment: Could you add the full class code ?

Comment: Use a [trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: I added images to show whats really going on

Comment: Just update your myPaynow function as return value function, Now, it is void function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected function callPayNow()
    {
        return new Paynow(
            '9644',
            '7e3bebb4-6dbf-4f8f-9e10-aceafd02c8db',
            'Return_url',
            'Result_url'
        );
    }
}
```

In your AnyController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AnyController extends Controller
{
    public function anyMethod()
    {
        $this->callPayNow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance , so for normal methods its working , but this one im trying to work with is a package in vendor folder , so i included it in the base controller  , then did excatly as you said. but then i get an error when trying to call its member functions ->  "Call to a member function createPayment() on null"

Comment: You never change manually vendor folder. I think my answer is correct for you?

Comment: Yeah your answer works well with all other methods , the one im working on is a package sort of  so it has its own classes and methods. When i try to call it now its failing to get its memember functions. But your answer is correct for the question i asked first. Thank you very much

Comment: i give you sample, in this case you must return $paynow in callPayNow function. This function return nothing now. BTW, if my answer is corret please mark as correct

Answer (score -1):

if I undersend you well,

Maybe the best approach is to create new controller that extends BasController:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{

    public function payNow()
    {
        return new Paynow(
            '9644',
            '7e3bebb4-6dbf-4f8f-9e10-aceafd02c8db',
            'Return_url',
            'Result_url'
        );
    }
}
```

And then in your other controller you can extend your new controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    //For example
    public function show($id, Request $request)
    {
        $payNow = $this->payNow();
        $payment = $payNow->createPayment($currentOrder, $request->get('email'));

        return response()->json("done");
    }

}
```

Paynow will be called in every controller that extends this controller.

Comment: Hie thank you for the assistance. So im using Laravel 7 and it has a file called controller.php which all other controllers are inheriting from. So in your answer do you mean that i must add that paynow function inside Controller.php so that all other contollers inheriting  can access it ?.

Comment: Hi, Yeah If you add "payNow" method as I added it here above, you will have access to it in any controller that extends this controller, but also you don't need to do that because of $this->payNow(); is called in the main constructor, if new controller is loaded function will be automatically called. But you can also remove $this->payNow(); and call it later in the controller that extends this controller. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Also in image that you provided you are getting "Call to a member function on null" because you are trying to call a function from nonobject, you are nor returning anything from myPaynow function you have to return that object that you are calling. I edited post, just to show you.

Comment: @ÖmerYilmaz, it doesn't matter really, you can take all the credit, I'm just trying to help brother,... :-)